# Subsetting by postcode (levels of factors)

Tags: r, subset

I have a problem whereby I want to match the start postcode and end postcode of a very large survey dataset, and put these results in a new dataframe.  I have created an example dataframe to use for the purpose of illustration.

```
ID = c(1,2,3,4,5) 
StartPC = c("AF2 4RE","AF3 5RE","AF1 3DR","AF2 4RE","AF2 4PE")
EndPC = c("AF2 4RE","NA","AF2 3DR","AX2 4RE","AF2 4PE")
data<-data.frame(ID,StartPC,EndPC)

data2 <- subset(data, StartPC==EndPC,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Using the above code, I want to create a dataframe (data2) which only includes the ID numbers whereby the start and end postcodes are the same.  However, I get the error message:

> Error in Ops.factor(StartPC, EndPC) : level sets of factors are different

The output needs just to have ID numbers 1 and 5 included in the new data table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That will be because

```
 Error in Ops.factor(StartPC, EndPC) : level sets of factors are different
```

Your two columns are factors, not characters. Factors are categorical variables, which are stored as integers and a lookup-table of 'levels'. Comparing them is actually comparing the underlying integers, so R makes sure you are comparing factors with the same levels. If not, then it decides you are doing a bad thing.

So convert to character:

```
> subset(data, as.character(StartPC)==as.character(EndPC),na.rm=TRUE)
  ID StartPC   EndPC
1  1 AF2 4RE AF2 4RE
5  5 AF2 4PE AF2 4PE
```

either on the fly like that, or make your data frame with characters in the first place, or make sure both columns are made with the same levels.

Comment: I would add that the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument can be helpful here when reading in a data.frame in the first place via `read.csv()` or the like.